# How do I get data from another table in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently trying to link some databases up for a project I'm working on for my business. Here's my below SQL I'm using for my PHP website.

```
$sql = "SELECT lname, fname, designation, agency, mobile, direct, email FROM contacts";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

At the moment my output goes like this to show what's in each row using e.g. `$lname=$lname["variable"]`

```
       if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          // output data of each row
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            
                  /* Print the row */ 
        echo "<tr>"."<td>". $lname . "</td><td>" . $fname . "</td><td>" . $designation . "</td><td>" . $agency . "</td><td>" . $mobile . "</td><td>" . $direct . "</td><td><a href='mailto:" . $email . "''>". $email. "</a><br>";
         }
}
```

I have another "clients" table, where each agency has an id - one that matches with $agency at this point. What I want to do is post the corresponding *companyname* column to that id.

How would I modify my code to do so (and access the column/rows from the secondary table)?

Comment: you'll want to look up and read about JOINs. it will let you combine data from two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood the question correctly, the answer should look something like

```
SELECT ct.lname, ct.fname, ct.designation, ct.agency, ct.mobile, 
ct.direct, ct.email, cl.company_name 
FROM contacts ct 
JOIN clients cl ON ct.agency = cl.id
```

The crux of it is the SQL JOIN clause.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt feedback David. I guess the question i have is how would I then commit this to a $agency variable. 

Would it be $row["cl.companyname"] ?

Comment: No, the resulting PHP array will use the column names (not table names or aliases) as keys. So it should be found at `$row['company_name']` which you can then assign to another variable if you want to.

More elegant is to alias company_name: `SELECT ... cl.company_name AS agency` and remove `ct.agency`

Comment: @devolution or you can simply `print_r($row);` to see  what  values the  key for better debbugging.